# ArquillianCucumber cannot find feature file

Tags: java, junit, jboss-arquillian, cucumber-java

I am trying to run a cucumber feature, whose stepdefinitions utilise arquillian-graphene and arquillian-drone, via Cukespace in a junit runner class. But whenever I try to run the junit test (via eclipse), I receive a 'feature not found' error. The feature file is located in src/test/java/features. Can anyone please identify why this is happening and how to solve it?

JUnit test class

```
package features;

import org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.api.RunAsClient;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.runtime.arquillian.CukeSpace;
import cucumber.runtime.arquillian.api.Features;
import cucumber.runtime.arquillian.api.Glues;

@RunWith(CukeSpace.class)
@Features("src/test/java/feature/SearchAutoAompletion.feature")
@Glues(features.stepdefinitions.SearchAutoCompletion.class)
@RunAsClient
public class TestsRunner {
}
```

Arquillian.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<arquillian>

<!-- clip -->
<extension qualifier="webdriver">
    <property name="browser">${browser}</property>
</extension>
<!-- clip -->

<extension qualifier="cucumber">
<property name="report">true</property>
<property name="reportDirectory">target/cucumber-report</property>
<property name="featureHome">src/test/java/features</property>
<property name="tempDir">target/custom/features</property>
</extension>

</arquillian>
```

Full error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No feature found
at cucumber.runtime.arquillian.ArquillianCucumber.buildFeatureList(ArquillianCucumber.java:233)
at cucumber.runtime.arquillian.ArquillianCucumber.getCucumberFeatures(ArquillianCucumber.java:187)
at cucumber.runtime.arquillian.ArquillianCucumber.performInternalCucumberOperations(ArquillianCucumber.java:136)
at cucumber.runtime.arquillian.ArquillianCucumber$InstanceControlledFrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(ArquillianCucumber.java:452)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$8$1.invoke(Arquillian.java:374)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.LocalTestExecuter.execute(LocalTestExecuter.java:60)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.ClientTestExecuter.execute(ClientTestExecuter.java:53)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createContext(ContainerEventController.java:142)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createTestContext(ContainerEventController.java:129)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createTestContext(TestContextHandler.java:130)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:92)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:73)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.test(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:136)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$8.evaluate(Arquillian.java:367)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$4.evaluate(Arquillian.java:245)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:426)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$200(Arquillian.java:54)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$5.evaluate(Arquillian.java:259)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$7$1.invoke(Arquillian.java:319)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.ClientBeforeAfterLifecycleEventExecuter.execute(ClientBeforeAfterLifecycleEventExecuter.java:99)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.ClientBeforeAfterLifecycleEventExecuter.on(ClientBeforeAfterLifecycleEventExecuter.java:72)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createContext(ContainerEventController.java:142)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createBeforeContext(ContainerEventController.java:124)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createTestContext(TestContextHandler.java:130)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:92)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:73)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.fireCustomLifecycle(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:159)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$7.evaluate(Arquillian.java:312)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at cucumber.runtime.arquillian.ArquillianCucumber.runChild(ArquillianCucumber.java:123)
at cucumber.runtime.arquillian.ArquillianCucumber.runChild(ArquillianCucumber.java:72)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2.evaluate(Arquillian.java:204)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:426)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$200(Arquillian.java:54)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:218)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:166)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:114)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:57)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:66)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy3.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:109)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:377)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Using jdk 1.8, and project dependencies are:

```
dependencies {
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.cukespace/cukespace-    core
compile group: 'com.github.cukespace', name: 'cukespace-core', version: '1.6.3'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-java8
compile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-java8', version: '1.2.5'
//https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.arquillian.graphene/graphene-webdriver
compile group: 'org.jboss.arquillian.graphene', name: 'graphene-webdriver', version: '2.1.0.Final'
//https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.arquillian.extension/arquillian-drone-webdriver-depchain
compile group: 'org.jboss.arquillian.extension', name: 'arquillian-drone-webdriver-depchain', version: '2.0.1.Final'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit
compile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java
compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '3.0.1'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-junit
compile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-junit', version: '1.2.5'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.cukespace/cukespace-parent
compile group: 'com.github.cukespace', name: 'cukespace-parent', version: '1.6.3'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to code like this:

```
  @Features({ "classpath: test/java/feature/SearchAutoAompletion.feature" })
```

Comment: Unfortunately that also gives same error that I already posted. I've also tried     @Features({ "classpath:     src/test/java/feature/SearchAutoAompletion.feature" }) but that also gives same error :(

Comment: hmm interesting, man the name of your package is features ... with S and you coded @Features("src/test/java/feature/SearchAutoAompletion.feature") ... /feature/  without S ... it might solve your problem :D